# Replace a character by another, unless it is located in between braces

Tags: regex

What I would like to do with the following string, is to replace all comas "," by tabulation, unless the said coma is between braces { }.

Say I have:

```
goldRigged,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,"{"LootItemID": "goldOre", "Amount": 1}"
```

The result should be:

```
goldRigged\t1\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\t1\t"{"LootItemID": "goldOre"**,** "Amount": 1}"
```

I already have: `\"(\\{((.*?))\\})\"` which allow me to match what's in between `{ }`.
The idea would be to exclude the content with something and match any comas with something like `\",^(\\{((.*?))\\})\"`
But I guess that by doing that it will exclude the comma itself.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: This is a CVS file, use a parser for this as it is more suitable. Using a regular expression is possible but it wouldn't be appropriate nor efficient for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need is called a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind. However, this would make up a quite complex statement:

Match all commas that are not preceeded by a opening brace as long as they were not previously preceeded by a closing brace (plus the reverted logic for the right side of the comma). This will result in an expression that is difficult to process because the regex engine constantly needs to run up and down your string from its current position what will be rather inefficient.

Instead, iterate over all characters of your string. If you match an opening brace, set an escape hint. Remove it, when you find a closing brace. When you find a comma, replace it when your escape hint is not set. Write your result to some sort of string buffer and your solution will b significantly more efficiant over the regex.

Comment: That is what I ended to do as like you said I felt like at the end the regex expression would be too complex. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a negative lookaround to achieve this:

`(?<![\{\}]),*(?![\{\}])` should work, try here: http://regex101.com/r/gG3oU1

Comment: This is not working since it would require the commas to be directly enclosed in braces.

Comment: @raphw those are negative lookarounds, which would capture a comma so long as it does not exist beside { or }.

Comment: Yes, and the regex will match if there is a brace right before the comma. Which it is not. Therefore, all the commas match what your example shows as well.

Comment: Ah, interesting how when you read the question 'beside' instead of 'between' it changes the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead `(?!expr)` and negative lookbehind `(?<!expr)` in your regex expression
for example you can code like this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
"goldRigged,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1, {\"LootItemID\": \"goldOre\", \"Amount\": 1}" ,
@"(?<!\{[^\}].*)[,](?![^\{]*\})", "\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your input line contain the { only in the last token?
If yes then you can try this brute force approach

```
echo "goldRigged,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,"{"LootItemID": "goldOre", "Amount": 1}"" | awk -F'{' '{one=$1;gsub(",","\t",one);printf("%s{%s\n",one,$2);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below regex is an expensive way of doing it. As suggest by @Sniffer a parser would be nicer here :)

```
(?=,.*?"{),|(?!,.*?\}),
```

First alternation

`(?=,.*?"{),` - make sure comma is outside the sequence `"{`

Second alternation

`(?!,.*?\}),` - make sure comma isn't inside the sequence `}"`

There will be edge cases that haven't been accounted for, that's the parser comes in

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need only one lookahead:

```
,(?=[^{}]*({|$))
```

reads: a comma, followed by some non-braces and then either an open brace or the end.

Example in JS:

```
> x = 'goldRigged,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,"{"LootItemID": "goldOre", "Amount": 1}",some,more{stuff,ff}end'
> x.replace(/,(?=[^{}]*({|$))/g, "@")
"goldRigged@1@0@0@0@1@0@0@0@1@"{"LootItemID": "goldOre", "Amount": 1}"@some@more{stuff,ff}end"
```

Note this doesn't work if braces can be nested, in this case you need either a regex engine with recursion (`?R`) or a proper parser.